# Using RANK() to assign a rank based on multiple criteria in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ranking-functions

I have a table similar to:

| Item | Class | Qty | Loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit1 | 1 | N |
| Apple | Fruit1 | 1 | NW |
| Apple | Fruit2 | 0 | W |
| Apple | Fruit3 | 1 | N |
| Orange | Fruit1 | 10 | SE |
| Orange | Fruit2 | 1 | SW |

I am trying to query all rows with the lowest `Class` that has the smallest **non-zero** `Qty` for each `Item`. So if the same `Item` has the same `Qty` for multiple classes, it would select the lowest `Class` (`Fruit1` < `Fruit2` < `Fruit3` < ...). I've tried using something like:

```
SELECT A.*, 
RANK() OVER(
PARTITION BY ITEM, CLASS
ORDER BY QTY ASC, CLASS ASC) AS item_rank
FROM fruits.info
WHERE QTY <> 0
```

to get a ranking to select, which isn't working. The results of the ranking should be:

| Item | Class | Qty | Loc | item_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit1 | 1 | N | 1 |
| Apple | Fruit1 | 1 | NW | 1 |
| Apple | Fruit3 | 1 | N | 2 |
| Orange | Fruit1 | 10 | SE | 2 |
| Orange | Fruit2 | 1 | SW | 1 |

I've would then use a nested select for `item_rank = 1`:

```
SELECT B.* FROM (
    SELECT A.*, 
    RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY ITEM, CLASS
    ORDER BY QTY ASC, CLASS ASC) AS item_rank
    FROM fruits.info
) B
WHERE B.item_rank = 1
```

to get the final results, which should be:

| Item | Class | Qty | Loc | item_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit1 | 1 | N | 1 |
| Apple | Fruit1 | 1 | NW | 1 |
| Orange | Fruit2 | 1 | SW | 1 |

How can I structure my `RANK()` in a way to achieve this? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` should only be used in ordering, not in partitioning. You want ranks for each `item`, not for each pair of `item` and `class`.

The (easy to fix) mistake in your attempt was to include `class` both in `partition by` and in `order by`; if you think about it for a second, that NEVER makes sense: if you partition by something, then further ordering by it (in each partition, where "it" is constant) makes no sense. Remove `class` from `partition by` and you should get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, makes sense and worked!